# bipartite graph for the yelp dataset rstudio

Tags: r, graph, bipartite

I am trying to produce a bipartite graph for a yelp sample dataset. If the user reviews one restaurant, one edge will connect this user and the restaurant, that is, `reviewed == 1`, otherwise, `reviewed == 0`.  How can I draw a bipartite graph based on the fact of whether users review the restaurants or not? x represents users; y represents restaurants. There are edges for the pairs `(u40, i7), (u40, i9), (u8, i12)`.

```
x <- c('u44', 'u44', 'u44', 'u40', 'u40', 'u8')
y <- c('i13', 'i1', 'i9', 'i7', 'i9', 'i12')
reviewed <- c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1)

data.frame(cbind(x, y, reviewed))
```

```
    x   y reviewed
1 u44 i13        0
2 u44  i1        0
3 u44  i9        0
4 u40  i7        1
5 u40  i9        1
6  u8 i12        1
```

**Update**

Thanks for the help from G5W but I have another question now. The graph has some overlaps and how can I improve my code to make it more readable? Here is my entire dataset: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rcURZBCOANrKQ4Kl_BmYW26LehrE0wye/view?usp=sharing

My code is shown below.

```
# Draw a bipartite graph
library(igraph)

g = graph_from_data_frame(data, directed=F)
g = delete_edges(g, which(data$reviewed == 0))

## set up vertex types to support layout as bipartite
V(g)$type = T
V(g)[unique(data$y)]$type  = F
V(g)$type

plot(g, layout=layout_as_bipartite)
```

[image]

**The lastest Update**

```
# Draw a bipartite graph
library(igraph)

data <- dput(data)

g = graph_from_data_frame(data, directed=F)
g = delete_edges(g, which(data$reviewed == 0))

## set up vertex types to support layout as bipartite
V(g)$type = T
V(g)[unique(data$y)]$type  = F
V(g)$type

plot(g, layout=layout_as_bipartite)
```

[image]

Comment: You added some new code and a picture, but no new question.  Is your question how to make your graph more readable?

Comment: Yes, exactly. How can I make the graph more readable, that is, there will be no overlap? Thanks for your time and patience.

Comment: I do not have a google drive account so I cannot get your data. However, it does not look very big.  Could you type `dput(data)` and paste the result into your question?

Comment: Hello G5W, It still overlaps with each other when adapting dput(data). Please see my updated code.

Comment: dput is so that you can pass your data to us so that we can work with it.  I cannot get to google drive to get your data set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will do this with `igraph`. It is fairly easy to make the graph connecting all of your user-restaurant pairs,  then delete the edges for which `reviewed = 0`. To get a nice plot, you will want to lay out the vertices as a bipartite graph.

```
library(igraph)

DF = data.frame(cbind(x, y, reviewed))
g = graph_from_data_frame(DF, directed=F)
g = delete_edges(g, which(DF$reviewed == 0))

## set up vertex types to support layout as bipartite
V(g)$type = T
V(g)[unique(DF$y)]$type  = F
V(g)$type

plot(g, layout=layout_as_bipartite)
```

[image: Graph laid out as bipartite]

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Since my dataset is actually much larger than the sample one, it has some overlaps. I have edited my questions. Could you please see it again? Really appreciate it.